# Defaulting variable to failed ajax request in Javascript

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to utilize the jQuery `.when` method to run an ajax request after several other requests succeed, and each one of those requests is optional. If it is not run, I do not want to issue the final ajax request. This is what I have so far:

```
var reference1 = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("reference1")).$data;
var reference2 = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("reference2")).$data;
var reference3 = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("reference3")).$data;

var reference1Post = false;
var reference2Post = false;
var reference3Post = false;

if (reference1.isValid()) {
    reference1Post = reference1.save();
};

if (reference2.isValid()) {
    reference2Post = reference2.save();
};

if (reference3.isValid()) {
    reference3Post = reference3.save();
};

$.when(reference1Post, reference2Post, reference3Post).then(function () {
    alert('save acct');
}, function () {
    alert('failure');
});
```

However, this causes the success route to trigger. It seems like I need to default the requests to a failed request and have it set to success only if it runs and it successful. Can I make this work using `.when()`?

Comment: You could use instead an array and push to it only requests needed, then use: `$.when.apply($, arrayOfReferencePost).then(...)`

Comment: Yes, but doing that won't fail the .when() method if an optional request isn't called.

Comment: Not if you don't push it into array, i mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ULGz7/  Sorry, using jsFiddle just to pass code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `false`, you can initialize them as failed promises:

```
var reference1Post = $.Deferred().reject().promise();
var reference2Post = $.Deferred().reject().promise();
var reference3Post = $.Deferred().reject().promise();
```

Comment: From DOC: `The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected.` But now setting optional deferred as resolved could work i guess. That's quite an interresting idea imho

Answer (score 1):

Using Vic's and A. Wolff's answers, this was the ending result:

```
var reference1 = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("reference1")).$data;
var reference2 = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("reference2")).$data;
var reference3 = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("reference3")).$data;

var requests = [];

if (reference1.isValid()) {
    requests.push(reference1.save());
} else {
    requests.push($.Deferred().reject().promise());
};

if (reference2.isValid()) {
    requests.push(reference2.save());
} else {
    requests.push($.Deferred().reject().promise());
};

if (reference3.isValid()) {
    requests.push(reference3.save());
} else {
    requests.push($.Deferred().reject().promise());
};

$.when.apply($, requests).then(function () {
    alert('save acct');
}, function () {
    alert('failure');
});
```

Comment: Ok, i missed this part of your question: `However, this causes the success route to trigger. It seems like I need to default the requests to a failed request and have it set to success only if it runs and it successful.` My bad! ;)

Comment: No worries. I have no idea what I'm talking about in this area, so I probably didn't describe it very well.